# Argument of type 'HttpParams' is not assignable to parameter of type 'URLSearchParams'

Tags: angular, typescript

I am updating an application to use a Angular 8 from Angular 4. I haven't really ever used Angular before and I'm running into several errors popping up. I have this error coming up:

`Argument of type 'HttpParams' is not assignable to parameter of type 'URLSearchParams'.`

when trying to run this

```
queryBatches(searchParams: HttpParams): Promise<PaginatedData> {
      return this.authService.generateAuthHeader({'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, searchParams).then(options => {
        return this.http.get(endpoints.query.batches({}), options)
          .map(response => {
            return new PaginatedData(response.json(), Batch);
        }).toPromise();
      });
    }
```

Here is what I'm importing

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {PaginatedData} from '../../models/common';
import {Batch} from '../../models/batch/batch.model';
import {AuthService} from '../auth/auth.service';
import endpoints from '../endpoints';
import {HttpParams} from '@angular/common/http'
import {Http, URLSearchParams} from '@angular/http';
import {BatchMismatch} from '../../models/batch/batch-mismatch-model';
import {BatchMismatchReviewer} from '../../models/batch/batch-mismatch-reviewer-model';
import {BatchMisMatchReload} from '../../models/batch/batch-mismatch-reload-model';
```

Any help with this issue would be apppreciated

EDIT:
I should also preface this with that I did not initially write this code.

generateAuthHeader:

```
generateAuthHeader(additionalHeaders?: {[index: string]: any}, searchParams?: URLSearchParams): Promise<RequestOptions> {
    if (this.cookieService.get('auth-cookie')) {
      let authCookie = JSON.parse(this.cookieService.get('auth-cookie')) as AuthCookie;
      const headers = new Headers({'Authorization': `Bearer ${authCookie.token}`});
      if (additionalHeaders) {
        for ( let headerValue of Object.keys(additionalHeaders)) {
          headers.append(headerValue, additionalHeaders[headerValue]);
        }
      }
      const options =  new RequestOptions({headers: headers, params: searchParams});
      return Promise.resolve(options);
    }
    else {
      return Promise.reject({status: 401});
    }
  }
```

Comment: What does generateAuthHeader looks like?

Comment: Added above, hopefully that helps

Comment: Can you try changing searchParams?: URLSearchParams to searchParams?: any and see if that helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is exactly what it says.

`generateAuthHeader`'s 2nd parameter should be of type `URLSearchParams`, but you are passing it an object of type `HttpParams`.

Now, if it actually is that type or not, you will need to console log to see the parameter.  If its just typed incorrectly, update the types so they match.  If `queryBatches` is indeed receiving an `HttpParams` object, then you will need to figure out how to make a new object to pass to `generateAuthHeader`